# forcing fullscreen for app in android

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen, window-managers

I want to create an app that runs in fullscreen.

So I have this code

```
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
          getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}}
```

But it doesn't work, does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say fullscreen, do you mean you want to hide the actionbar.?

Comment: yes, the bar with back and home button and stuff

Comment: (the bar at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` inside `public void UI(){...}` and write `this.getWindow().setFlags(...)` instead of `getWindow().setFlags(...)`

And this attribute in your `manifest` in the `application` tag if you want entire app in full screen or add it in `activity` tag you want make a full screen of.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and remove the below code

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

Comment: I did, however, it says that the method requires a ; after UI ?!

Comment: @BaxterStockman why are you creating UI() method? If you are not using it anywhere else in your activity then remove it. And why does it say `method requires a ; after UI`? Is it because you set contentView in UI() or because you added context, this.getWindow?

Comment: @BaxterStockman contentView must be set after getWindow() to make it work. You should remove UI() method

Comment: Right, the method was a dumb idea, so I removed it and but the setContentView after get.window, but now it crashes I am going to update the code in the original post

Comment: Hi, ok, it doesn't crash anymore but the action bar & navigation is still there

Comment: still there, my code looks like this 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}}

Comment: @BaxterStockman I made a little mistake too, if you are adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to `<application>` of manifest then you don't need `requestWindowFeature(...)` and `getWindow()`. So try using only Theme.NoTitleBar.FulScreen in manifest and put requestWindow and getWindow in comment

Comment: Ok, so now I only added the theme in the manifest but it doesn't change anything, navigation is still there

Comment: @BaxterStockman Then there must be any other issue, now I can't help anymore

Comment: So what you are saying is, that the simple theme change in the manifest will do the fullscreen?

Comment: @BaxterStockman Yes can see this http://blog.vogella.com/2011/02/28/android-hidding-the-status-and-title-bar/

Comment: using that crashes my app everytime :(

Comment: @BaxterStockman it works for everybody, it should work for you too. If doesn't then there might be something you have written that affects this code.

Comment: I don't think so, and I found many other threads saying that it doesn't work. Thanks anyways